# Connecting to Virtual Box ssh server

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

Is it possible to connect via ssh client (e.g. Putty) from one computer on a LAN to the ssh server running on VirtualBox'ed Linux on Windows 7 on another computer in the same LAN? Is yes, then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux on the VM Host must be connected via bridged network. Then you can access it over SSH via Guest IP. Also you can configure a NAT network and forward a Port e.g 2222 from the Host to the Port 22 of the VM. When you connect via putty, you need to change the default port to 2222. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html .